# Why is Multimap not camel cased?

Tags: naming-conventions, guava

This one really annoys me (and my colleague).

It's not

- Hashmap
- Treemap
- org.apache.commons.collections.Multimap
- etc.

So why didn't anyone notice this naming convention flaw or is there an intention behind this typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "[multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap)" (one word, entirely lowercase) refers to a specific data structure. It's different from a "map", which is another data structure. So since they're different data structures, they have different names.

The [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface you usually use in Java is the chosen name for an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), also known as "map", "dictionary", "hash", etc. Likewise, Guava's [`Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface is their representation of the `multimap` data structure.

Comment: This makes sense. I haven't ever thought this was an option, since word compounds always seemed seldom in the English language to me.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a typo. Guava's `Multimap` is **not** a `Map`, i.e. it does not extend `Map` interface (and it shouldn't). See [Guava's wiki page on this topic](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap-is-not-a-map):

> - `Multimap.get(key)` always returns a non-null, possibly empty collection.  This doesn't imply that the multimap spends any memory associated with the key, but instead, the returned collection is a view that allows you to add associations with the key if you like.
> - If you prefer the more `Map`-like behavior of returning `null` for keys that aren't in the multimap, use the `asMap()` view to get a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`.  (Or, to get a `Map<K,`**`List`**`<V>>` from a `ListMultimap`, use [the static `Multimaps.asMap()` method](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap%28com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap%29). Similar methods exist for `SetMultimap` and `SortedSetMultimap`.)
> - `Multimap.containsKey(key)` is true if and only if there are any elements associated with the specified key.  In particular, if a key `k` was previously associated with one or more values which have since been removed from the multimap, `Multimap.containsKey(k)` will return false.
> - `Multimap.entries()` returns all entries for all keys in the `Multimap`.  If you want all key-collection entries, use `asMap().entrySet()`.
> - `Multimap.size()` returns the number of entries in the entire multimap, not the number of distinct keys.  Use `Multimap.keySet().size()` instead to get the number of distinct keys.

On the other hand, [Apache Commons Collections' `MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) (not the capital "M" in map) extends `Map`, but it's a bit awkward in use, plus Apache devs also came to consludion that extending and mimicking map-like behavior in multimap is not what user wants, so they deprecated `MultiMap` (yes, **you should not use old `MultiMap` interface and its implementations in new code!**) and now recommend using [`MultiValueMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) instead - it does **not** extend `Map` and has quite similar API to Guava equivalent.

Comment: This is a good explanation about the implementation of guava, but doesn't really answer the question, why the name is spelled as it is.

Comment: Au contraire, "Guava's `Multimap` is not a `Map`", just like multiplayer is not a player (and why would you spell that with "P")? Regarding example with `HashMap` (and not `Hashmap`), if you see implementations for Guava `Multimap` - they follow the convention and `HashMultimap` is one of them (not `Hashmultimap` as you may argue).

Comment: Multiplayer is an adjective though. MultiPlayer would emphasize, that something is a player being multi (this doesn't make sense of course) as an ArrayList shows that it is a list (noun), whereas multifunctional means, something is functional (adjective) in many ways.

Comment: Couldn't make up better example, as English is not my first language, but anyway - @OlivierGrégoire has a point - multimap is a name of a data structure.